# change foreign key attributes in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys

Is it possible to change the attribute of a key/foreign key (without deleting and re-creating them)?

I've the following structure:

```
CREATE TABLE `articles` (
..
`LKZ` smallint(3) NOT NULL,
`FID` int(4) NOT NULL,
..
) ;
CREATE TABLE `firm` (
`LKZ` smallint(3) NOT NULL,
`FID` int(4) NOT NULL,
`Name` text NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`LKZ`,`FID`),
KEY `FID` (`FID`)
);
ALTER TABLE `firm`
ADD CONSTRAINT `firm_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`LKZ`) REFERENCES `articles` (`LKZ`) ON DELETE NO ACTION,
ADD CONSTRAINT `firm_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`FID`) REFERENCES `articles` (`FID`);
```

I want to add the attributes `UNSIGNED ZEROFILL` to the fields `FID` and `LKZ`:

```
ALTER TABLE `articles` CHANGE `LKZ` `LKZ` SMALLINT( 3 ) UNSIGNED ZEROFILL NOT NULL, CHANGE `FID` `FID` INT( 4 ) UNSIGNED ZEROFILL NOT NULL;
ALTER TABLE `firm` CHANGE `LKZ` `LKZ` SMALLINT( 3 ) UNSIGNED ZEROFILL NOT NULL, CHANGE `FID` `FID` INT( 4 ) UNSIGNED ZEROFILL NOT NULL
```

But even get the following error for both tables:

```
#1025 - Error on rename of '.\pindex\#sql-3eec4_ef' to '.\pindex\articles' (errno: 150)
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look into your foreign keys. Probably there is another table with a foreign key referencing the primary key you are trying to change.

If should also try to find out which table is causing the error. To do so, you can run SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS, and then on the column STATUS look at the "LATEST FOREIGN KEY ERROR" section.

Keep in mind that foreign key names are global and must be unique in the database context.